# Pigeonhole principle of 81 numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, pigeonhole-principle

Please someone can help me to prove this. We have a 9x9 square panel with some arrangement of the numbers 1... to 81 in it.
Prove that there are at least two neighboring numbers the differnce between them bigger than 6 (horizontally or vertically) prove that???

Comment: What has your question to do with `complex-numbers`?

Comment: This question has been posted 2-3 days in a row. Do you guys share the same homework or something?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681326/pigeonhole-principle-hard-question/